# node-serialport doesn't list nor detect USB devices connected to laptop

Tags: javascript, node.js, usb, port, electron

I am building an app using [`Electron`](http://electron.atom.io) and [`node-serialport`](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport) and I don't get the list USB devices connected to my laptop (e.g : mouse, speakers)

I am using this code :

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

SerialPort.list(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Number of results : " + results.length);
});
```

And the output is `Number of results : 0`.

When I check through my `Device Manager` :

[image]

Here's my configuration :

- **Electron**: `1.4.5`
- **SerialPort version**: `4.0.5`
- **NodeJS Version**: `6.9.1`
- **Operating System and Hardware Platform**: `Windows 8.1 / 64 bits`

Answer (score 3):

Serialport means `COMx` port in windows. Your device list contains none.

USB has a "serial" in its name, but this has *nothing* to do with the (older) serial ports.

Some USB devices may implement interfaces that are accessible as COM ports. But there are no such devices connected to your PC in your screenshot.